# Poisson equation in frequency domain

Tags: numerical-analysis, nonlinear-equations, poisson

I need some help in numerically solving the nonlinear Poisson's equation for electrons in frequency domain. The steady-state equation is:
\begin{equation}
\nabla.(\epsilon\nabla\varphi) = q\left(n_i\exp\left(\dfrac{\varphi-\Phi_n}{V_\text{T}}\right) -N_D\right)
\,.
\end{equation}

In small-signal analysis, we have $\varphi = \varphi_{\text{DC}} + \delta\varphi$, with $\delta\varphi <<\varphi_{\text{DC}}$. 
This yields:
\begin{equation}
\nabla.\Big[\epsilon\nabla(\varphi_{\text{DC}} + \delta\varphi)\Big] = 
q\left(n_i\exp\left(\dfrac{\varphi_{\text{DC}} + \delta\varphi-\Phi_n}{V_\text{T}}\right) -N_D\right)
\end{equation}
which I can further simplify to:
\begin{equation}
\nabla.(\epsilon\nabla\varphi_{\text{DC}}) + \nabla.(\epsilon\nabla\delta\varphi) = 
q\left(n_i\exp\left(\dfrac{\varphi_{\text{DC}} + \delta\varphi-\Phi_n}{V_\text{T}}\right) -N_D\right)
\,\,.
\end{equation}

I do not know how to proceed from here. That is, how should I treat the exponential term on the RHS and what are the basic assumptions in doing so?

Comment: Honest question. Normally a Fourier transform would convert a function of time to a function of frequency, but Poisson doesn't have a time dependence. It is not obvious to me how this can be done in this case.